# Testing a method instead of testing a whole file in Netbeans w/ JUnit

Tags: java, testing, netbeans, junit

I'm using Netbeans 6.8 and the finest-grained way to run my JUnit tests from the IDE appears to be to right-click a class under `Test Packages` and click `Test File`

In Eclipse it's possible to narrow the scope to testing an individual method in a given test harness. How do I test only one individual test out of a harness in Netbeans?

Comment: In IntelliJ it's possible to right-click at the test-method name and select run, perhaps there is a similar way to run it in Netbeans?

Comment: It's possible to see methods and right click them in Netbeans' Navigator view, but as far as I can tell so far, there's no context menu item to test that method. Thanks though, I'm still digging :)

Comment: NetBeans now has just such a feature; see my answer below.

Comment: Have been using this feature in Netbeans 7.4 and works great! https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/run_debug_focused_test_method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**: NetBeans supports this (e.g. see NetBeans 6.8). Just right click the passed or failed test and then click 'Run Again' or 'Debug'. Or right click in the editor and click Run/Debug focused test.

**Old**:

To my knowledge this is not possible. And maybe the NetBeans-guys had in mind that always all tests should pass for one unit. I know that tools should not limit the developers, but If one method takes too long - maybe you should consider a separate integration test?

Also take a look at [this post](http://blog.jonasbandi.net/2009/07/netbeans-showstopper-running-tests.html). (BTW: in maven projects running tests of a unit **is** possible ...)

Comment: Thanks for coming back and updating this :)

Comment: no problem. as a netbeans user this bothered me too. is this working for you? it seems to be only available for maven projects!?

Comment: Right click on the editor and click Run/Debug Focused Test Method not work for me for gradle project in Netbeans 13.

Answer (score 14):

In NetBeans 7.1, open the unit test file, right click within the specific unit test and select "Run Focused Test."

Comment: This is still true in NB 8.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans 7.1 "Run Focused Test" isn't working with my build, so I'm using use a test group to mark the tests I want to run.

```
@Test(groups={"DEBUG"})
```

You can configure Netbeans to run these tests by adding `-Dgroups=DEBUG` to your "Debug Test File" action in the project properties.

Note: these are TestNG methods run with maven/surefire.

Comment: Did you ever get this working Roger?  All of a sudden, my project will not run focused tests - I am not sure why - we have a few developers on the project (including writing JUnit tests).  But the test I have done will not run.  I'm using Netbeans 7.1.2

Comment: Yes, I'm using a @Test(groups={DEBUG}) to run individual tests. I setup NetBeans to use -Dgroups=DEBUG and when I run "Debug Test File". It works well and I also add other system properties for debugging (e.g. browser=chrome).

Note the groups attribute is for TestNG. JUnit has it's own grouping annotations. But yeh, my Netbeans doesn't run focused tests out of the box - I thought it was because I use inner classes for my test cases (http://www.ninthavenue.com.au/how-to-use-inner-classes-for-your-unit-tests).

Answer (score 0):

The option "Run Focused Test" was grayed-out on my project because there was no action named "run.single.method" in project.xml.

Workaround to get it working:

1) create new "run.single.method" action in project.xml file (you could copy "run.single"
action).

project.xml fragment:

```
<action name="run.single.method">
 <script>nbproject/ide-file-targets.xml</script>
 <target>run.single.method</target>
 <context>
  <property>run.class</property>
  <folder>test/src</folder>
  <pattern>\.java$</pattern>
  <format>java-name</format>
  <arity>
   <one-file-only/>
  </arity>
  </context>
</action>
```

2) create new "run.single.method" target in ide-file-targets.xml (you could copy
"run-selected-file-in-src") *and make sure the test tag has a parameter
"methods" using the property "${method}"*.

ide-file-targets.xml fragment:

```
<target name="run.single.method" depends="compile">
 <fail unless="run.class">Must set property 'run.class'</fail>
 <junit maxmemory="256m" fork="true" haltonerror="true" haltonfailure="true" printsummary="on" jvm="${jdk.dir}/bin/java" showoutput="true">
  <sysproperty key="build.basedir" value="${basedir}"/>
  <!-- method attribute makes the selected method to be unit tested only -->
  <test name="${run.class}" methods="${method}"/>
  <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
  <classpath refid="CLASSPATH"/>
 </junit>
</target>
```

Now you can use the right mouse menu  "Run focused test".

The option "Run focused test" might also be temporary be grayed-out when the project is scanning

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone is wondering focus testing is also possible via IntelliJ by right click on a specific test and run